# Flutter Bloc keeps rebuilding widget without state changing

Tags: android, flutter, dart, provider, bloc

Learning Bloc pattern and I got stumbled on this. In the first page ExamBloc handles fetching exams and displaying. Once the user selects the exam, quiz page is called with the selected exam. QuestionBloc fetch the questions and pass it to stateful widget to display questions. The question is displayed properly.

However, the whole page is continuously rebuilt for no reason. I tried statefull and stateless widget of QuizScreen widget but still can't stop rebuilding.Any help appreciated.

´´´

```
 class _QuizScreenState extends State<QuizScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final QuestionBloc questionBloc = context.bloc<QuestionBloc>();
    questionBloc.add(FetchQuestion(widget.selectedExam));

    return
       BlocBuilder<QuestionBloc,QuestionState>(
         bloc: questionBloc,
         builder: (context, state) {
           print('entrance'+state.toString());
           if (state is QuestionIsLoading)
             return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
           if (state is QuestionIsLoaded){
            final QuizBrain quizBrain =QuizBrain(state.questionList);
            List<QuestionModel> ql=state.questionList;
             return Scaffold(
                 body:  Choices(quizBrain: quizBrain, questionList: ql));}
         },
       );
  }
}


class Choices extends StatefulWidget {

 Choices({@required this.quizBrain,@required this.questionList});
 final List<QuestionModel> questionList;
 final QuizBrain quizBrain;
  @override
  _ChoicesState createState() => _ChoicesState();
}

class _ChoicesState extends State<Choices> {
  var _selection;

  onChangedRB(String  value) { setState(() { _selection = value; });
  print('onchange clicked');
  print(value);
  widget.quizBrain.nextQuestion();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[

        Text(
          widget.quizBrain.getNextQuestion().content,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        Container(child: RB(choice:widget.quizBrain.getNextQuestion().content,value:'A',groupValue:_selection,onChanged:onChangedRB
        )),


      ],
    );

  }
}
```

´´´

Answer (score 4):

You are making infinite loop:

In your builder you are adding new event. After event is parsed it adds state and this state is being passed to builder:

*BlocBuilder* is listening to *QuestionBloc* state changes. With *BlocProvider* you are adding event, which adds new state to *BlocBuilder*.

Short story long, you should not add same type of Bloc events

(`BlocProvider.of<QuestionBloc>(context).add(FetchQuestion(widget.selectedExam))`)

in same Bloc builder (`BlocBuilder<QuestionBloc,QuestionState>`).

Comment: I made the change you recommended, I get  this error.  BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type Question Bloc.         No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to

Comment: BlocProvider<QuestionBloc> has to be a parent of widget from which you are calling questionBloc.add